# During a French TGV strike, must I go to the station to get a full refund for my ticket?

Tags: trains, france, cancellations, high-speed-rail

I booked a TGV a while ago with a discount card, the conditions of the ticket are that I can get refunded entirely before the departure of the train, and a fee is withheld if I cancel my ticket the day of the trip.

I received a text saying that the train will not run and I can receive a full refund if I cancel my trip. But when I go online, if I click "Cancel" the only option is to pay the fee (my trip is today). On the mobile app, the "Cancel" button is not even available.

I would like to know how I can get a full refund. Apparently according to the text I received, I can get a refund if I go to the station. But is there a way to get a refund without going to the station (as I do not want to take the train any more)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [international site](http://help.ch.voyages-sncf.com/en/useful-information/traffic-info) of SNCF, you can ask a refund via post:

> To obtain a refund write to:
>
> Service relations clients SNCF
>
> 62973 Arras cedex 09
>
> FRANCE

It specifies that you need to send:

> the original tickets if you have received them
>
> your booking reference
>
> your full contact details (full name, address and phone number)

Note that I haven't actually tried this.

Answer (score 2):

You can call the SNCF phone line on `36 38`, they will cancel your tickets based on its reference . Assuming you old that big old kind of tickets, not an e-billet or a regional ticket. Black and white, without a QR-code but with the mention `à composter avant l'accès au train`, your reference are the six letters next to `dossier` on the lower right corner. 
Then you will need to return your ticket to a station or by mail to actually get refunded.

According to the [French FAQ](http://www.sncf.com/fr/greve-questions-pratiques) (wich has not been translated in english) you should be able to cancel any ticket on a strike day with no fee. Even usually-not-refundable tickets (like Prem's) are refundable.
This pages says that you can even get refunded after departure times on strike days.

Good to know ; on strike, and if your train is cancelled, you can take any other train that goes to your destination without additionnals fees -- even with non-exchangeable tickets.

Those details may varry from one strike to another, depending of it's duration and geographical area.

Comment: The question is how to do it *in practice*. I am pretty sure Vince is familiar with the theory. You do cover that a little bit (+1) but you might want to add details on this aspect to improve your answer.